# How do I turn a numpy array into a tensor in "Tensorflow"?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow

I tried to test some learning networks after I completed training with a tensorflow.

But my test image is [512 512 1] data of channel 1 in 512 horizontal and 512 vertical pixels.

I changed the image data to a numpy array.

The tensor network should be [? 512 512 1] It looks like this.

How do I convert a numpy array to a tensor? ([512 512 1] -> [? 512 512 1])

Comment: What is the leading `?` dimension for?

Comment: A message says ...     ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (512, 512, 1) for Tensor 'images:0', which has shape '(?, 512, 512, 1)'

Comment: Yes, but what is the `?` dimension? Batch size?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just have to append one dimension

```
arr = your_image # [512, 512, 1]
new_arr = np.expand_dims(arr, 0)

tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(new_arr)
```

Now you can use feed dict or something else.

Comment: thsnks you very very much!